# I want to display one custom ListView record to second Custom ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have created two Custom listView,both  have  two textView and one EditText ,I want to show all  record which is entered  edittext accept  textView on second Custom ListView on on Button Click Event ,in my code it doe't show to any thing in second list view but it show on toast

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList;
String rate ;
String itemnam ;
String quan;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menuitem);
    final ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final ListView lisView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);


    MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> map;

    /*** Rows 1 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Butterscotch");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 10");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 2 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Birthday Cake");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 100");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 3 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Black  Crunch");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 102");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 4 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Industrial Chocolate");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 200");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 5 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Coffee Molasses Chip");
    map.put("Code", " Rs 500");
    MyArrList.add(map);    


    lisView1.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter(this));






    Button btnGetItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetItem);
    btnGetItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {


    int count = lisView1.getAdapter().getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)lisView1.getChildAt(i); // Find by under   LinearLayout
    TextView nam = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.ColID);

    TextView rat = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.ColCode);

    EditText quan = (EditText)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);

    String Code = rat.getText().toString();
    String Country = quan.getText().toString();
    String name = nam.getText().toString();

    Log.d(Code, Country);
    Toast.makeText(Mmnue.this,name + ", " + Country+ " , " +Code ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    lisView2.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter2(getApplicationContext()));

    } 




    }
    });



    }


    public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
    private Context context;

    public CountryAdapter(Context c)
    {
    //super( c, R.layout.activity_column, R.id.rowTextView, );
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    context = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return MyArrList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mmnue, null);

    }

    // ColID
    TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColID);

    txtID.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("ID") +".");

    // ColCode
    TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColCode);
    txtCode.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Code"));

    // ColCode
    //EditText quan = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
//  quan.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Code"));
  return convertView;

    }

    }

    public class CountryAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter
    {
    private Context context;

    public CountryAdapter2(Context c)
    {
    //super( c, R.layout.activity_column, R.id.rowTextView, );
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    context = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mmnue, null);

    }

    // ColID
    TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColID);
    //txtID.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("ID") +".");
    txtID.setText(quan);
    // ColCode
    TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColCode);
//  txtCode.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Code"));
    txtCode.setText(rate);

    EditText quant = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
//  txtCode.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Code"));
    quant.setText(itemnam);

    return convertView;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String rate ;
String itemnam ;
String quan;
```

Where are you initialising them?

First you did it in following but now you made local viriables:

```
String Code = rat.getText().toString();
String Country = quan.getText().toString();
String name = nam.getText().toString();
```

With which you do nothing before setting the adapter

```
lisView2.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter2(getApplicationContext()));
```

Nothing will happen:

```
 txtID.setText(quan);
 txtCode.setText(rate);
 quant.setText(itemnam);
```

You should fill an arrayList and use a second arraylist it in your second adapter. Just like for your first.